# Are there any video tutorials available for game programming with Max?

Tags: 3dsmax

Are there any videos on how to make a small game using Max? I mean is it only done in Max or are there other things used? I am a newbie in game programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3DS Max is a 3D modelling tool. [There are several video tutorials available](http://www.google.com/search?q=3DS%20max%20video%20tutorials) all over the internet (of varying quality). However, **you can't make a game just using Max** -- all it does is modelling and rendering. You'll need to use something else entirely, or at least something else in conjunction with Max, in order to make a game.

**[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) is a similar kind of modelling tool that does have a built-in game engine that can be used.** It's also *much cheaper* than Max (because it's free). There's [lots of documentation and educational material](http://www.blender.org/education-help/) on Blender's website and elsewhere on the internet. You may also want to consider looking at [Unity](http://unity3d.com/). There are several other game construction tools available as well.

You could also teach yourself to program -- I'd recommend [Python](http://python.org/) as a first language, if you choose to do this. This will give you a lot of control and flexibility in the games you create, but it will involve a much steeper learning curve (for example if you choose to go this route you'll likely be learning to develop very simple text-based games for some time before you are ready to tackle the complexity of 3D graphics and loading 3D models and scenes exported from Max).

Comment: The UI for Blender is garbage, though

Answer (score 2):

As the other two people have said, you cannot make a game in Max. If you are a designer/artist and you wanna get into game development there are a couple of tools available online that you might like to consider picking up:

1) **Construct:** http://www.scirra.com/construct/

This is an open source (free) game development tool targeted specifically for 2D games. It's also targeted at people like you who aren't programmers because you don't need to learn programming to use it. The interface allows you to build a game without writing any code

2) **Game Maker:** http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker/

Basically a similar thing to Construct. It has a free version as well as a pro version. Also doesn't require programming

3) **Game Salad:** http://gamesalad.com/

Another similar thing, except this one is Mac only.

Now these three are great if all you want to do is mess around with game development, have some fun and all, but if you're serious in getting into some real game development, unfortunately you **MUST** learn programming. That's not to say you need to be amazing at it, but you do need to know it relatively well. And the tool I very very much recommend you use if you want to get into it is called **Unity3d: http://www.unity3d.com**

Unity is a free game development tool that is very popular nowadays amongst indie developers. Its interface is very well made. Basically if you want to get into serious game development - it doesn't get any easier then Unity. You do need to write code to get stuff to happen in Unity, but in my opinion it's very easy to learn. The language you will be using in Unity is Javascript, C# or Boo. I recommend Javascript

The final option is.. don't develop games. If you want to stay in 3DSMax, go ahead and become amazing at it, then you can make content for games such as 3D models, animations, textures, etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: suppose i made a moving ball animation in 3ds max , is it possible to add some mouse click function on that ball

Comment: Not that I know of.. I'm not a 3DS user myself (I'm a maya user). You might be able to get some kind of interactivity happening if you were to delve into Max scripting, which is basically programming - and if you were gonna do that then you may as well leave 3dsmax for something that actually offers interactivity as a focus. If you for some reason MUST do it in 3dsmax then maybe this could help http://www.eonreality.com/raptor/

Answer (score 1):

3ds Max is not used for programming games. It is frequently used in game development, but the relevance of 3ds Max to game development is that you can create 3D models using it and then export them to load in a game engine.