# How to make simple game from max model

Tags: 3dsmax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any video tutorials available for game programming with Max?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11757/are-there-any-video-tutorials-available-for-game-programming-with-max)

Suppose i have model of simple 3d ball made in 3ds max. i just want to make simple game for fun . the scene will have only one ball , which will move with cursor.

I know there may be other tools for game but i just want to know how to export 3ds max model in game

Comment: How you export the model usually depends on what you are exporting it to. If you could give a bit more information as to which engine you are targeting then someone might pipe up with plugin or steps to go from a max model to one for that engine.

Comment: i have no knowledge of gamr prog , i only know max

Comment: The answers you get will be the same as the other question you asked with the same subject matter.  You need a game engine.  That engine will dictate how you export your max file and get it in game as an art asset.  Unity3D is probably the easiest to use as you can just drop in a 3ds file and it'll export it for you.